# Css with id and class

Tags: css

Hello and greetings to you all.

I have a strange reaction with css in one website that i'm making.

There is this code

```
<a class="instagram-photo image" id="p1130472628000663001_176824616" href="PROFILE" target="_blank" data-name="NAME" data-caption-std="Colors #thefeditor" data-caption="Colors #thefeditor <a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;INSTA LINK;>View Photo</a> " data-created="1448982860" data-author="AUTHORNAME" data-likes="87" data-comments="0" data-profile="PROFILE LINK" rel="group"><img src="IMAGE LINK"><span class="journal-meta">Example Name<span>username</span></span><span class="icon">Image</span></a>
```

The above image is set with the following background color.

```
media="all"
.classic-view .instagram-photo.image {
    background-color: #3dc0f1;
}
```

I'm trying to change the blue color (#3dc0f1) color to this

```
background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
```

With no luck because i want to change the color ONLY to this id

```
id="p1130472628000663001_176824616"
```

because if i go to the custom css and put this css code

```
.instagram-photo 
{
   background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

It changes all the images, but i want to change the images with the ID that i gave you above.

I have tried

```
#p1130472628000663001_176824616.instagram-photo {
       background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
    }
```

But it didnt work. Any idea of how can i make it work? Thanks!

P.S. the answer below is also correct but i also managed to do it with

```
a[id*="_176824616"][class*="image"]
{
background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That last selector should work, and you shouldn't need `!important` (it's better to not use that at all). Also your HTML seems to be invalid, which is a common reason for CSS not to work.

Comment: You say you want to change the `images with an Id`. Make sure you dont have duplicate elements with the same `id`! id must be unique.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but `<` inside an attribute value should be escaped as `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just doing:

```
.instagram-photo#p1130472628000663001_176824616
{
   background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

That way, you are declaring a rule to CSS that says that you want to set the background color to an element of class `instagram-photo` and with id having your id - notice that the class and id are concatenated to one phrase on the rule. This is done in order to specify the rule containing both class and id on a specific element and not the nested ones.

Also, consider that for simplicity, you could simply do:

```
#p1130472628000663001_176824616
{
   background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

By "saying" to CSS you want to apply the rule only to the element(s) with the specific ID, without taking into consideration its class - this is specific on your case, so it should work fine.

In addition, consider avoiding using `!important`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior on your rules and violates the sequence the rules are applied.

Comment: This doesnt solve his problem, because the same element has the id and the class. He must change the markup for this.

Comment: The selector `#p1130472628000663001_176824616.instagram-photo`, that OP used should do that too, right?

Comment: I will correct your answer of course you helped me and it's working but i solved it on my own using css attribute 
`a[id*="_2231898729"][class*="image"]
{
background-color:rgba(255,215,0,0.6) !important;
}`